# Python regex capturing & AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture the word "Avenue" in "Bukit Batok Avenue 3":

```
street_name = "Bukit Batok Avenue 3"
m = re.compile(r'(\S*?)\s\d$', re.IGNORECASE).search(street_name).group(1)
```

Group(1) doesn't work as the following is returned:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Or it would be cool to code the regex so that the word (Avenue) before a number(3) is captured, is that possible?

Comment: [It works](https://ideone.com/XAzDrT).

Comment: Move line "street_name = ..." before making regex on it.
"no attribute 'group'" propably means that regex did not match.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the last word using this regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'(\w+)\s*\d$', "Bukit Batok Avenue 3", re.I)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(12, 20), match='Avenue 3'>
>>> re.search(r'(\w+)\s*\d$', "Bukit Batok Avenue 3", re.I).group(1)
'Avenue'
```

Without using `group()` over `Match` object:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*\d$', "Bukit Batok Avenue 3", re.I)
['Avenue']
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*\d$', "Bukit Batok Avenue 3", re.I)[0]
'Avenue'
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the prompt answer, I realised that .group(1) can't be used as it will deem the grouping unusable:

    if re.search(r'\d+$', street_name):
        m = re.search(r'(\w+)\s*\d$', street_name, re.I).group(1)
    else:
        m = re.compile(r'\b\S+\.?$', re.IGNORECASE).search(street_name)
        
    if m:
        street_type = m.group()
        if street_type not in expected:
            street_types[street_type].add(street_name)
    
---> 10         street_type = m.group()
     11         if street_type not in expected:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Sorry for the non-pretty code above. It seems I can't answer my own question, so has to post on comment. 

I wonder if there's a regex to select the word ('Avenue' in this case ) before a number ('3' in this case) without having to use .group().

Comment: @jmulan, use `.group()` in one place or the other -- when assigning `m`, or when querying `m`, but not both. And if you make it the former, you need to have an exception handler for the case where there wasn't any match.

Comment: @ritesht93 Thanks for prompt answer again, much appreciated. Sadly, it has to be re.compile as the output has to be this format: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(12, 20), match='Avenue'>, a string or list deem it not usable for later grouping in street_type = m.group()